# Can't make CustomBinding work in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

I wrote a simple console application supposed to run on Linux.

The application uses a precompiled dll (which works just fine I guess) except one thing: the remote server uses custom binding configuration and cannot be reconfigured. The configuration is as follows:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="163840000" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000"
                      allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Ntlm" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                      decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true"
                      maxBufferSize="655360000" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Ntlm" realm="" transferMode="Buffered"
                      unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="true" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      </httpsTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="REMOTE_LINK_HERE" binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="CONTRACT_NAME"
            name="myBinding">
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

So, the server uses Ntlm for authentification. Since the app must run on Linux and thus outside the domain I had to set credentials in code rather than start application via 'runas' which is only available in Windows. Here is my code:

```
var client = new ...;

if (client.ClientCredentials != null)
{
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential
                    = new NetworkCredential(options.UserName, options.Password, options.Domain);
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel
                    = TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification;
}
```

The problem is - my application runs just fine in Windows on native .NET CLR. Once compiled with xbuild and started on Linux I have the error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Use ClientCredentials to specify a user name for required HTTP Ntlm authentication.

Is there any workaround for this?

P.S. I found the similar message in Mono's Bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2415), but the patch provided seems to do nothing with a CustomBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying various hacks, finnaly found a workaround. The workaround is - to set             `ClientCredentials.UserName` property. Unfortunately, it is get-only, so I had to use reflection to set private fields values. Since they are different in native .NET and mono's, the code looks a bit dirty, but still works.

Here is my code:

```
var credentials = client.ClientCredentials.UserName;

var userNameProperty = credentials.GetType()
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower() == "username");

if (userNameProperty != null)
    userNameProperty.SetValue(credentials, Options.UserName);

var passwordProperty = credentials.GetType()
    .GetField("password", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (passwordProperty != null)
    passwordProperty.SetValue(credentials, Options.Password);
```